# server keeps shutting off using grunt serve due to connect:livereload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

Here is the error I'm getting, I'm relatively new with using grunt on personal projects, anybody have any clue? strong text

Salmans-MacBook-Pro:ang-news Salman$ grunt serve

> > Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
> >
> > Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
> >
> > Local Npm module "grunt-ng-annotate" not found. Is it installed?

Running "serve" task
Warning: Task "connect:livereload" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: have you installed these with NPM?

Answer (score 1):

install the modules with:

`npm install grunt-contrib-connect grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-ng-annotate  --save-dev`